# How to add CQ variables onto Sitecatalyst mapping framework?

Tags: aem

How to add CQ variables onto Sitecatalyst mapping framework?

As clicking on New button opens Add New component dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, [in the documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/integrating_with_adobe_marketing_cloud/sitecatalyst.html#par_title_32).

The summary is that you need to do two things. First you need to use the CQ_Analytics.record() function (it's JavaScript) to expose the values you want to send to SiteCatalyst (for example, page path or page depth).

Then you need to expose those same values to the SiteCatalyst framework, so you can map them to your report suite in the Cloud Services Configuration. To do so, you'll need to add the analytics (nt:unstructured) configuration node to your cq:Component. On it, set cq:trackevents, cq:trackvars, cq:componentName, and cq:componentGroup accordingly. Then you'll have that component available to you in the CSC.